# What are typical unit tests for a key-value collection?

Tags: test-design, unit-tests

I've implemented a key-value collection, that's accessible as a dictionary (so values can be retrieved by keys) and a list of entries (key-value pairs).

I'm not a tester myself and I have a hard time coming up with a good test cases to see, if there isn't some bug in implementation - but I didn't find through google any "typical" cases for quite a typical functionality.

I've added bunch of records, I've retrieved them (by key, by iteration), comparing to the source keys and values lists, I've created a test where I add records then delete random ones to see, if all remaining are actually there, but I wonder what I might be missing, before I start using that collection in my code.

To summarize: can anyone provide a list - just high-level concepts - what to test a key-value collection for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Googling for Java Hashmap test.  I very quickly found [this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pivot/trunk/core/test/org/apache/pivot/collections/test/HashMapTest.java), and I am sure you can find many others.